# Gradle location is incorrect how to reslove android gradle rrror

Tags: android, gradle

How to resolve this error, android studio project?

> Gradle location incorrect

[image: How to resolve this error,android studio project gradle location incorrect]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Well, you could enter the correct location ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this path:

`C:\Users\MyHome\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\<some random folder>\gradle-1.6`

you can replace your own gradle version with 1.6 in above path.